# How to handle wchar_t ** with python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, wchar-t

I've a dynamic C library (say *foo.so*) in which there's a function having the following prototype

```
wchar_t **foo(const char *);

/*
  The structure of the return value is a NULL terminated (wchar_t **),
  each of which is also NULL terminated (wchar_t *) strings
*/
```

Now I want to call the function through this API from python using **ctypes** module

Here's the snippet I've tried with :

```
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL("foo.so")

text = c_char_p("a.bcd.ef")
ret = POINTER(c_wchar_p)
ret = lib.foo(text)
print ret[0]
```

But it's showing the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "./src/test.py", line 8, in
>
> print ret[0]
>
> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_ _ getitem _ _'

Any help to get things going in python is keenly appreciable.

P.S : I've cross checked the functionality of foo("a.bcd.ef") in a sample **C** code & [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7747.png) is what the return pointer looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing steps are to define the [arguments](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) and [return type](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types) of `foo`:

```
from ctypes import *
from itertools import takewhile

lib = CDLL("foo")
lib.foo.restype = POINTER(c_wchar_p)
lib.foo.argtypes = [c_char_p]

ret = lib.foo('a.bcd.ef')

# Iterate until None is found (equivalent to C NULL)
for s in takewhile(lambda x: x is not None,ret):
    print s
```

Simple (Windows) test DLL:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

__declspec(dllexport) wchar_t** foo(const char *x)
{
    static wchar_t* y[] = {L"ABC",L"DEF",L"GHI",NULL};
    return &y[0];
}
```

Output:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```